# Command line install Mongo regardless of OS

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, scripting, operating-system

Trying to write a script that will install Mongo, if it doesn't exist, at least across Ubuntu, Red Hat Linux, and Mac OSX.

Here's the idea:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  if [$mongoDoesntExist]; then
    if [ $myOS = "Ubuntu" ]; then
      # install Mongo on Ubuntu
    else if [ $myOS = "Red Hat Linux"]; then
      # install Mongo on Red Hat Linux
    else if [ $myOS = "Mac OSX"]; then
      # install mongo on Mac OSX
    else
      echo "Please visit https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/installation/ to install Mongo on your OS"
    fi
  fi
```

Comment: You can call the `os_version` function to get the OS name and version - see https://github.com/elifarley/shell-lib/blob/master/lib/base.sh

Comment: Thanks, I did end up doing that, and then opted to go build Conda from that information and install packages more easily that way...

Answer (score 0):

Try [cross-installer](https://github.com/elifarley/cross-installer), which aims to be able to install software in a uniform way, regardless of OS:

```
# Install cross-installer
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elifarley/cross-installer/master/install.sh | sudo sh

# Install  MongoDB
sudo xinstall add mongodb
```

Comment: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/cross-installer’: Permission denied` (even with sudo)

Comment: I've fixed some bugs and tested on Debian and CentOS. Perhaps you want to retry and if that doesn't work, report an issue at https://github.com/elifarley/cross-installer/issues to avoid cluttering SO (please tell on which operating system it didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I opted to first detect OS and install the appropriate Conda distribution, then easily install dependencies as needed with Conda, e.g.

```
download_miniconda() {
    echo "Downloading Miniconda for Python dependencies..."
    OS_BIT_TYPE="$(uname -m)"
    OS_ARCHITECTURE="$(uname -s)"
    if [ $OS_BIT_TYPE == "i686" ]; then
        OS_BIT_TYPE="x86"
    fi
    if [ $OS_ARCHITECTURE == "Darwin" ]; then
        OS_ARCHITECTURE="MacOSX"
    fi

    MINICONDA_INSTALL_FILE="Miniconda2-latest-$OS_ARCHITECTURE-$OS_BIT_TYPE.sh"
    MINICONDA_DOWNLOAD_URL="https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/$MINICONDA_INSTALL_FILE"
    $(curl -O $MINICONDA_DOWNLOAD_URL)
    $(chmod +x $MINICONDA_INSTALL_FILE)
}

install_miniconda() {
    echo "Installing Miniconda..."
    echo "$(./$MINICONDA_INSTALL_FILE -b -p $HOME/miniconda)"
    echo "$(rm $MINICONDA_INSTALL_FILE)"    
}

confirm_miniconda_installed() {
    if hash conda 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "Miniconda installed!"
    else
        echo "Failed to install Miniconda. Please visit http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html to install and then try rerunning this script, making sure that Miniconda is accessible in the PATH"
    fi
}

update_script_startup_file() {
    echo "if [[ \":\$PATH:\" != *\":\$HOME/miniconda/bin:\"* ]]; then" >> $STARTUP_FILE
    echo "  export PATH=\"\$PATH:\$HOME/miniconda/bin\"" >> $STARTUP_FILE
    echo "fi" >> $STARTUP_FILE
}

add_miniconda_to_path() {
    # temporary update to PATH for this script
    export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/miniconda/bin"

    # permanent update to PATH for user's convenience
    if [ -n "`$SHELL -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'`" ]; then
        STARTUP_FILE="$HOME/.bashrc"
        update_script_startup_file
    elif [ -n "`$SHELL -c 'echo $ZSH_VERSION'`" ]; then
        STARTUP_FILE="$HOME/.zshrc"
        update_script_startup_file
    else
        echo "Couldn't automatically add Miniconda to the PATH of your preferred terminal. We suggest working from Bash or ZShell." 
    fi
}

create_conda_environment() {
    if hash conda 2>/dev/null; then
        CONDA_ENVIRONMENTS="$(conda env list)"
        if [[ "$CONDA_ENVIRONMENTS" != *"words2map"* ]]; then
            conda create --name my_mongo_environment --yes mongo
        fi
    fi
}
```

Of course, users can change mongo and install any dependencies covered by [Conda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which covers over 700+ packages...

FYI this is a part of a larger installation sequence for the [words2map](https://github.com/overlap-ai/words2map/blob/master/install.sh) library, so any updates will be reflected there.